# PDO Grab data where name = name

Tags: pdo, where-clause

so I've been trying to grab data from a name, like this

So my table look like this:

Table = database then ID, ip, name.

So when a name is entered I want to check if there is an IP attached to it in my database if there is then print all ip's else don't do anything..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy you didn't show what you tried.

A simple select would do it:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT ip FROM `databases` WHERE name = :name');
$stmt->execute(array('name'=>$name));
$row = $stmt->fetch(FETCH_ASSOC);
```

then compare in PHP:

```
if($row['ip'] ==  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']){
   //IP attached to it in my database
}
```